# Scope by User in marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, user

I allow myself to contact you because I have a question concerning the setting of the scope by user.
When implementing Marketing Cloud, the By user scope was checked.
For technical reasons between Salesforce and Marketing Cloud.
We would like to uncheck it.
I would just like to confirm if there are any impacts regarding the data model, Email Studio, contact Builder...
Thanks for your help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**Scope by User**

> This option configures data access on the Marketing Cloud Connect user
> initiating the send. Reports and campaigns that are visible to the
> user are available for selection as a target audience for sending. The
> list of subscribers returned is limited to what the user initiating
> the send has access to view.

**Non-Scope by User**

> This option configures data access on the Salesforce system user,
> typically an administrator. Choose this option to allow Marketing
> Cloud Connect users to send to all subscribers in a report or campaign
> that the Salesforce system user can access. Subscribers are not
> filtered based on the user running the report.

This basically means that everyone will be able to access all data, even if they are not allowed to access it in Sales Cloud. It has no implications on the data model etc., just on who can see what data.

The full list of considerations can be found here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_account_configuration_for_user_data_access.htm&language=en_US&type=5